# How could we aproach development of touchscreen with morphing surface or morphing keyboard?

Tags: electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, materials, electromagnetism, consumer-electronics

There is this technology of [braille e-readers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_e-book). It is relatively simple and reliable but it never had much commercial success probably because small customer base.

In past a company called [Tactus](https://youtu.be/wrSKbTzc4BI?feature=shared) tried implementing something similar to touchscreens to equip it with pop up buttons. Their product was sloppy and allowed only for elevation of predefined set of buttons so it was not success. But the concept itself seems promising and desirable.

Now days there came to be [foldable tablets/notebooks](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-spectre-foldable-17-cs0097nr) with second screen in place of keyboard.

It seems like a logical step to develop a touchscreen-keyboard hybrid that can freely transform it's surface to elevate and form any possible keyboard with buttons of any shape, configuration and picture displayed on it.

But the question is how much doable that logical step is? Do you think it is?

Do you think some notebook, phone or touchscreen company is developing this right now?

How would you approach developing it?

I had two ideas.

One is based on fixed pop up liquid cells and trying to make them as small as possible and pack them on the screen as densely as possible. Basically a tactile pixels. But this does not seem as practical.

My second idea was using some kind of ferrofluid or magnetic nano particles in liquid. And it turns out ferrofluid displays are a thing and there are people who make [open source version of it](https://youtube.com/watch?v=5PFgVtzsXHM&feature=shared). This is not a display with transforming surface or transforming keyboard but it shares some technological challenges with it. What they have is ferrofluid dancing on mosaic of magnets. For a keyboard we would need the top surface of the container to be soft and bend but not get penetrated. For a transformable display we would either need the ferrofluid to be transparent or to have very flexible screen resting on top of the ferrofluid layer. Also if we want ferrofluid to feel harder when hit without using that much strong magnetism, we could perhaps give it some additional non-newtonian behavior similar to oobleck. So it would be oobleck-like ferrofluid. But perhaps ferrofluid is not the way to go

Also right now there are automobile developers like BMW and General Motors who develop shape changing matter for use in morphing aerodynamics adjusting cars. One of the companies trying to do something like this actually bought the Tactus technology.

PS: As a limit of possibility imagine trying to develop something as intricate as being able to draw tactile reliefs of mandalas and fractals (like the ball in sand) or visualize music in cymatic sense and doing so continually either directly using those principles or being able to imitate it. The question is, how would you reproach developing it.

Comment: `How would you approach developing it?` has no "wrong" answer, therefore such a question is off topic here ... please edit your question so that it is not opinion based